# RuntimeError on running ALBERT for obtaining encoding vectors from text

Tags: nlp, runtime-error, huggingface-transformers, encoder-decoder

I’m trying to get feature vectors from the encoder model using pre-trained ALBERT v2 weights. i have a nvidia 1650ti gpu (4 GB) , and sufficient RAM(8GB) but for some reason I’m getting Runtime error saying -

> RuntimeError: [enforce fail at …\c10\core\CPUAllocator.cpp:75] data.
> DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate
> 491520000 bytes. Buy new RAM!

I’m really new to pytorch and deep learning in general. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong?

My entire code -

```
encoded_test_data = tokenized_test_values[‘input_ids’]

encoded_test_masks = tokenized_test_values[‘attention_mask’]

encoded_train_data = torch.from_numpy(encoded_train_data).to(device)

encoded_masks = torch.from_numpy(encoded_masks).to(device)

encoded_test_data = torch.from_numpy(encoded_test_data).to(device)

encoded_test_masks = torch.from_numpy(encoded_test_masks).to(device)

config = EncoderDecoderConfig.from_encoder_decoder_configs(BertConfig(),BertConfig())

EnD_model = EncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained(‘albert-base-v2’,config=config)

feature_extractor = EnD_model.get_encoder()

feature_vector = feature_extractor.forward(input_ids=encoded_train_data,attention_mask = encoded_masks)

feature_test_vector = feature_extractor.forward(input_ids = encoded_test_data, attention_mask = encoded_test_masks)
```

Also 491520000 bytes is about 490 MB which should not be a problem.

I tried reducing the number of training examples and also the length of the maximum padded input . The OOM error still exists even though the required space now is 153 MB , which should easily be managable.
I also have maxed out the RAM limit of the heap of pycharm software to 2048 MB. I really dont know what to do now…

Comment: Pass smaller batches.

Comment: But I have a massive data set to work with. Will looping through and converting small batches to the respective feature vectors work?

Comment: Yeah... It should work.